# Apache2, setup dynamic subdomains on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, subdomain

Simple question how?

Now I have such enabled host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName git.land

DocumentRoot /home/sergey/public_html/git.land/public_html

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /home/sergey/public_html/git.land/public_html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And added rule in hosts

```
127.0.0.1   git.land
```

When I enter on "http://git.land" it show proper direction. But when I try to get in "http://some.git.land" is stucks. Thinks a lot and then redirect on prev. page (without subdomain).

I want add subdomains to localhost for testing but I don't know what should I use for it. Base things I knew, I tried but it gives nothing.

Also can I (maybe) somehow change it from .htaccess (I searched around and found people use them to get subdomains name without any configuration in hosts).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by this config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/sergey/public_html/git.land/public_html
    ServerName other.land
    ServerAlias *.land
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName land
    DocumentRoot /home/sergey/public_html/git.land/public_html

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/sergey/public_html/git.land/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn 
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It works ONLY when all cases (I mean subdomains) setup in hosts.